# VueJS: React to State change through mapGetters receiving arguments

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

## Question

How can I pass arguments to a `getter` inside `mapGetters`? Is this on the right way to react a state change on `widgetFetched.posts` and `posts` at the same time? In other words, can my `getter` react to these changes?

---

## Explanation

I'm trying to make my Component react to a change in `State` in my `Vuex Store` through a `getter`. To achieve this, I'm using `mapGetters` inside my Component. But this `getter` receives an argument, an `id` to filter my state (that is flatten).

I have two states (that are dictionaries): `widgetsFetched` and `posts`. One `widgetFetched` has a property called `posts` that is an array of `Post.Id`. And the state `posts` is a dictionary whose keys are `Post.Id`.

So, I have a `getter` called `getPostsByWidgetId` that takes one argument `widgetId`. Then, my `getter` returns an array containing posts filtered by `widgetFetched.posts`'s ids.

---

## Store

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    widgetsFetched: {
        1: { id: 1, done: true, posts: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
        2: { id: 2, done: false, posts: [5, 6] }
    },
    posts: {
        1: { name: '...', id: 1, content: '...' },
        2: { name: '...', id: 2, content: '...' },
        3: { name: '...', id: 3, content: '...' },
        4: { name: '...', id: 4, content: '...' },
        5: { name: '...', id: 5, content: '...' },
        6: { name: '...', id: 6, content: '...' }
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getPostsByWidgetId: (state, getters) => (widgetId) => {
      if (widgetId && state.widgetsFetched[widgetId] && state.widgetsFetched[widgetId].posts) {
        return state.widgetsFetched[widgetId].posts.map((postId) => {
          return state.posts[postId]
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

---

## Component

My components looks like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="post in posts(this.widget._id)" >{{ post.id }} - {{ post.score }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    name: 'reddit',
    props: ['widget'],
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        posts: 'getPostsByWidgetId'
      })
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

---

## Examples

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `mapGetters` does not support passing arguments. But you can achieve a similar effect with this code:

```
computed: {
  posts() {
    return this.$store.getter.getPostsByWidgetId(this.widget._id)
  }
}
```